# Legend as filled rectangles in plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm writing charts for a client and the style requires the legend to be (a) placed within the plotting area and (b) mapping fill to filled rectangles with labels. My current attempt looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data(diamonds)

diamonds %>%
  group_by(color, cut) %>%
  summarise(price = mean(price)) %>%
  #
  ggplot(aes(x = color, y = price, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  annotate("rect", xmin = "D", xmax = "E", ymin = 6000, ymax = 6500, fill = "red") + 
  annotate("text", x = 1.5, y = 6250, label = "Fair")
```

[image]

(The fact that the colour is "red" and not the ggplot red is irrelevant: the colours are manually set. Also, obviously I would need the labels for the other fill variables)

This is adequate, but I would like to know:

1. Is there a way to detect where ggplot has white space and place the legend there (or create white space in which to place the legend)?
2. Is there in general a more automatic solution than `annotate`?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there is no way to "automatically detect the correct place to put the legend within the plot", at least not one that will *always* work. At some point you will have to fiddle with it yourself.

You can move the default legend into the plot via something like:

```
diamonds %>%
    group_by(color, cut) %>%
    summarise(price = mean(price)) %>%
    #
    ggplot(aes(x = color, y = price, fill = cut)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                     position = "dodge") + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.position = c(0.25,0.8),
                legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

if that's appealing to you.